# Is File.ReadAllLines lazy loaded when using with LINQ Where?

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-loading, file.readalllines

I would like to know if the following code is lazy evaluated or will crash in the way I handle possible exception of `ReadAllLines()`. I know for sure that `Where` clause is lazy evaluated but I'm not sure when I use it with `ReadAllLines()`.
A possible explanation of how and why would be appreciated.

[image: File.ReadAllLines Exceptions]

```
var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(line =>
{
    line = line.Trim();
    return line.Contains("hello");
});

string search;
try
{
    search = fileLines.Single();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    ...log the exception...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `T[]` is never lazy, since it requires a consecutive block of memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`File.ReadAllLines` is not lazy loaded, it loads all into memory.

```
string[]  allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

If you want to use LINQ's deferred execution you can use `File.ReadLines` instead:

```
var fileLines = File.ReadLines(filePath)
    .Where(line =>
    {
        line = line.Trim();
        return line.Contains("hello");
    });
```

This is also [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `ReadLines` and `ReadAllLines` methods differ as follows: When you use
>   `ReadLines`, **you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned**; when you use `ReadAllLines`, **you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned** before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient.

But note that you have to be careful with `ReadLines` since you cannot use it twice. If you try to "execute" it a second time you'll get an `ObjectDisposedException` since the underlying stream is already disposed. **Update** [This bug seems to be fixed.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535097/bug-in-the-file-readlines-method-of-the-net-framework-4-0)

<strike>This will cause an exception for example:</strike>

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
string header = lines.First();
string secondLine = lines.Skip(1).First();
```

You cannot use it either to write to the same file since the stream is still open.

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadLines(path)); // exception:  being used by another process.
```

In these cases `File.ReadAllLines` is  more appropriate.